# How do I set the src value of an iFrame to the text in an input field?

Tags: html, variables, iframe

How would I be able to change the site in an iFrame to the value in an input field.

I want to do something like this:

```css
iframe {
  height: 320px;
  width: calc(100vw - 24px);
  resize: both;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<input type="text"/>
<button type="submit"></button><br>
<iframe src="https://xijxaj.glitch.me/new/index.html">
```

Answer (score 1):

If I got you right, you want to change the iframe source using text url in the text input. You can use JavaScript to do this.

```
<script>
    document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", ()=>{
        let src = document.querySelector("input").value;
        document.querySelector("iframe").setAttribute("src", src);
  });
</script>
```

In the code above, we add an event listener when you click the submit button, it will get the value inside the your input and set the iframe src attribute to it.

If you are using this as part of a form, you can change the event listener from "click" to "submit" and it will do the same.

Comment: lol i was trying to be first to post but you were to fast :)

Comment: yea lol I'll go ahead and upvote. Seems legit.

Comment: How would I be able to make the script run? I'm new to HTML so I sometimes have no clue what I'm doing.

Comment: @Speedblocks : You can use script tag. I edited it the code above so you can easily use it by copying it to the end your HTML file, just before the closing body tag </body>

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery:

```js
$('input#url').on('propertychange paste keyup',function(){
  
  var url = this.value;
  $('#frame').attr('src', url);
  
});
```

```css
iframe {
  position:fixed; 
  top:7; 
  left:0; 
  bottom:0; 
  right:0; 
  width:100%; 
  height:90%; 
  border:none; 
  margin:0; 
  padding:0; 
  z-index:99999;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html> 
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>display-webpage-in-iframe-dynamically</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  
<input type="text" id="url" name="url" value="https://">
  
<iframe src="" id="frame"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't know how to use jQuery. Can I put it in a <script> tag?

Comment: Yes, you can put it in the script tag. Make sure you call it though with ```<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
```